# Script to run a command for few seconds

Tags: python, bash

I have a command which keeps sending messages and I cannot rate limit it. What I want to do is call the command, let it run for 5 seconds, sleep for 1 minute and then call the script again.

Normally I would write:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    myCommand 
    sleep 60
done
```

What I want to do is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    run myCommand for 5 seconds and stop. 
    sleep 60
done
```

I am not limited to bash, if any other scripting language can do this in an easier way, I don't mind exploring that. Note: myCommand Keeps running and has to be interrupted.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate and if this answer was honestly answered we should consider making the myCommand stoppable with an option opposed to trying to kill a child ...

Answer (score 0):

In Python this would be:

```
import time

while True:
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() <= start + 5:
        do_the_action()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: myCommand Keeps running and has to be interrupted. Updated question